# Reading CSV File In Memory Stream Into DataReader

Tags: c#, csv, oledb, memorystream, datareader

I have a CSV file stored in the database (binary format). Is there a way to load it into memory and then use a `DataReader` to read its contents? Or do I really have to save it to the file system and then read it using `OleDb`. I've done the latter and it works perfectly fine. I'm just wondering whether I could avoid saving to the file system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader Best regrds.

Comment: `DataReader` through `OleDb` is **not fast** to parse CSV so _maybe_ your solution has better performance (benchmark before put effort on this). Moreover you do not need to save CSV to file system because you can do it in memory (even with a `MemoryStream`). If your CSV is stored in a datbase you may even consider to do **parsing on server-side** to consume data with a plain `IDbConnection`.

Comment: @Adriano: Could you please post an answer with a sample code that could get me started? Using a `MemoryStream` is exactly what I was looking for.